# Choose window to select when there are more than two visible

Tags: window

When I have four windows visible and I want to move from one to another, I use `C-x o`.  But that cycles through the windows in a predetermined order, namely:

1  3

2  4

Without intending to do so, just because my brain and fingers go on auto-pilot, I've fallen into the weird habit of using a combination of `C-x 0`, `C-x 1`, `C-x 2`, `C-x 3`, and `bury-buffer` (which I've bound to `C-x c`) to select the buffer I want while keeping them in a chosen order.

Is there a more direct way for me to move from window 1, say, to window 4?

Comment: Sorry, to be clear, the predetermined order is NW, SW, NE, SE (as I'm sure you all know).

Comment: Have a look at the built-in library `windomove.el` and see if you like some of the interactive functions:  https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WindMove

Comment: This has got to be a duplicate, but I don't have time to track down the duplicate(s).

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the behaviour you want using [ace-window package](https://github.com/abo-abo/ace-window).
Calling `ace-window` (if you have just two windows open, will just switch to the other window) will highlight the first character of each window and pressing said character will switch you to that buffer. Here's a [gif](http://oremacs.com/download/ace-window.gif) demonstrating how it works.

You can also use [avy](https://github.com/abo-abo/avy) package to switch between open windows.